# Using gedit via remote ssh (on Dreamhost server)

Tags: ssh

Is this possible? I already tried using ssh -X user@host, and while there were no errors, it still wouldn't allow me to edit my files via ssh.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: is it a permissions issue? use `gksudo`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sshfs`](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) to access the file and use `gedit` locally. Or you can use `vim`/`emacs`/`nano`. Dreamhost likely blocks X-forwarding, however.